# System of congruences when $gcd(m,n) \not= 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have to solve this system but I don't know what I did wrong, since the result should be:
 $ x \equiv19\;(mod\;56)$.
$$
\begin{cases}
  x \equiv 3\;(mod\;8) \\
   x \equiv 19\;(mod\;28) \\
\end{cases}\\
$$
$$
3 + 8k = 19 + 28h\\
8k-28h = 16\\
2k−7h=4\\
$$
$$
k_0 = -5;\;h_0 = -2\\
k = -5+7t;\;h = -2+2t\\
$$
$$
x = 3+2(-5+7t)\\
x \equiv 7\;(mod\;14)\\
$$

Edit: Do I have to use this theorem?$$
\begin{cases}
  x \equiv a\;(mod\;p) \\
   x \equiv b\;(mod\;p^k) \\
\end{cases}\;
⇒x \equiv b\;(mod\;p^k) 
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
  x \equiv 3\;(mod\;2^3) \\
   x \equiv 19\;(mod\;7*2^2) \\
\end{cases}\\
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
  x \equiv 3\;(mod\;8) \\
   x \equiv 19\;(mod\;7) \\
\end{cases}\\
$$

chinese theorem:
$$
...\\
  x \equiv 131\;(mod\;56) \\
  x \equiv 19\;(mod\;56) \\
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one method to use is the Chinese remainder theorem to solve these congruences.

You were on the right track in the beginning, and we can see how $ x \equiv3\;(mod\;8)$ gives us $x=3+8k$.

We can then substitute our $3+8k$ for $x$ in the second congruence to get $$ 3+8k \equiv19\;(mod\;28)$$
Solving for $k$ we find $k \equiv 2\;(mod\;28)$, so $k=2+28h$.

If we substitute this $k$ back into our first equation for $x$, we get $$x=3+8(2+28h)$$
$$\implies x=3+16+56h$$
$$\implies x=19+56h$$
This ultimately gives us $x \equiv 19\;(mod\;56)$, the desired result.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have never used it in this way. Does it have any sort of conditions to consider?

Comment: Not particularly. As long as the congruences are true, which you can check after solving, this can be used for any number of equivalence statements, not just 2 in this example. If this answered your question don't forget to approve the answer so it doesn't stay unanswered!

Comment: @Shyvert Beware that while the stated answer is correct, the derivation is not. The correct solution of $\, 8k\equiv 16\pmod{28}$ is $\,k = 2\pmod{\color{#c00}7},\,$ which back-substituted yields the claimed result.

Answer (score 0):

$7\bmod14$ is not $3\bmod8$. You need to remove a factor of $4$ from the $\bmod28$ congruence to get a system of relatively prime moduli:
$$x\equiv5\bmod7$$
Then use the Chinese remainder theorem to get the correct result.